# Using Navigation in MasterDetailPage with Autofac and Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, autofac, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to use Autofac in Xamarin.Forms project. I created basic samples successfully, even used ViewFactory for some more complicated samples.

However, I'm unable to use `MasterDetailPage` **along with Navigation**.

I'm using factories and services written by [Jonathan Yates](http://adventuresinxamarinforms.com/2015/04/29/creating-a-xamarin-forms-accordion-control-without-custom-renders/). You can find his code [`here`](https://onedrive.live.com/?id=AD85BE12C255C5CB%21969&cid=AD85BE12C255C5CB&group=0&parId=AD85BE12C255C5CB%21814&action=locate)

My Application Bootstrapper:

```
protected override void ConfigureApplication(IContainer container)
{
    var viewFactory = container.Resolve<IViewFactory>();
    var mainPage = viewFactory.Resolve<TestViewModel1>();

    var navigationPage = new NavigationPage(mainPage);
    var masterPage = new ContentPage();
    masterPage.Title = "asd";
    _application.MainPage = new MasterDetailPage()
    {
        Master = masterPage,
        Detail = navigationPage

    };
}
```

My `TestViewModel1` has a command that navigates to `TestViewModel2`:

`ButtonCommand = new Command(async()=>await _navigator.PushAsync<TestViewModel2>());`

However, the app crashes with Exception saying

> Cannot cast from source type to destination type.

This happens when the `Navigator` is pushing the next page.

**StackTrace:**

> "  at TestIoc.TestModule+<>c.b__0_0 () [0x00000] in C:\Users\dushyantb\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\TestIoc\TestIoc\TestIoc\TestModule.cs:27 \n  at TestIoc.Views.PageProxy.get_Navigation () [0x00001] in C:\Users\dushyantb\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\TestIoc\TestIoc\TestIoc\Views\PageProxy.cs:39 \n  at TestIoc.Navigator.get_Navigation () [0x00001] in C:\Users\dushyantb\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\TestIoc\TestIoc\TestIoc\Services\Navigator.cs:26 \n  at TestIoc.Navigator+d__8`1[TestIoc.ViewModels.TestViewModel2].MoveNext () [0x0003a] in C:\Users\dushyantb\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\TestIoc\TestIoc\TestIoc\Services\Navigator.cs:58 "

what am I doing wrong?

**Note: The navigation works when there's no MasterDetailPage.**

Comment: Could you share the stack trace of the exception ?

Comment: I've updated the question with stack trace. Please check it out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure not to override the PageResolver, eg. don't take the override Jonathan uses in his WeatherApp sample:

```
builder.RegisterInstance<Func<Page>>(() => ((NavigationPage)Application.Current.MainPage).CurrentPage);
```

The default implementation of the PageResolver Func in the core component takes care of MasterDetail scenarios. See AutoFacModule.cs:

```
            // default page resolver
            builder.RegisterInstance<Func<Page>>(() =>
            {
                // Check if we are using MasterDetailPage
                var masterDetailPage = Application.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage;

                var page = masterDetailPage != null 
                    ? masterDetailPage.Detail 
                    : Application.Current.MainPage;

                // Check if page is a NavigationPage
                var navigationPage = page as IPageContainer<Page>;

                return navigationPage != null 
                    ? navigationPage.CurrentPage
                        : page;
            }
        );
```

I have tested MasterDetail scenario with NavigationPage DetailViews succesfully with Jonathan's framework. So it should work.

In my case, the bootstrapping code is

```
        protected override void ConfigureApplication(IContainer container)
        {

            // set main page
            var viewFactory = container.Resolve<IViewFactory>();

            var mainPage = viewFactory.Resolve<MainPageViewModel> ();
            _application.MainPage = mainPage;

        }
```

That means, i have a MainPageView, which is a MasterDetailPage and which takes care of setting up it's child views:

```
    public class MainPage : MasterDetailPage
    {
        public MainPage (IViewFactory viewfactory)
        {
            Master = viewfactory.Resolve<MenuPageViewModel>();

            Detail = new NavigationPage (viewfactory.Resolve<DetailViewModel1>());

        }
    }
```

The MenuPageViewModel  also uses IViewFactory to switch the MasterPages' Detail:

```
public class MenuPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    IViewFactory _viewFactory;
    public MenuPageViewModel (IViewFactory viewFactory)
    {
        _viewFactory = viewFactory;

        ShowDetail1Command = new Command (ShowDetail1);
        ShowDetail2Command = new Command (ShowDetail2);
    }


    public ICommand ShowDetail1Command { get; set;}
    public void ShowDetail1() {
        var mainPage = _viewFactory.Resolve<MainPageViewModel> ();

        ((MasterDetailPage)mainPage).Detail = new NavigationPage (_viewFactory.Resolve<DetailViewModel1> ());
    }

    public ICommand ShowDetail2Command { get; set;}
    public void ShowDetail2() {
        var mainPage = _viewFactory.Resolve<MainPageViewModel> ();

        ((MasterDetailPage)mainPage).Detail = new NavigationPage (_viewFactory.Resolve<DetailViewModel2> ());
    }

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks!
 I was already using the part that takes care of the MasterDetail scenarios in `AutofacModule`, BUT I was also using `builder.RegisterInstance<Func<Page>>(() =>
                ((NavigationPage)Application.Current.MainPage).CurrentPage);` in my own Module which was getting registered after `AutofacModule`. Hence the previous registration was never executing and I couldn't figure out why!

Just had to remove that one statement.

Comment: I'm no expert, but I found your navigation weird. I might be wrong, but looks like you're setting a new page to the `Detail`, instead of navigating.

Comment: That's right, it was just a quick hack. But nevertheless, you can register the DetailView with AutoFac as .SingleInstance() and you will always get the same instance of your DetailPage.

Comment: @DushyantBangal can you share your module.cs and bootstrapper.cs as I am having error like ViewModel is not register. Thanks

Comment: @jaketalledo, heres my whole project https://1drv.ms/u/s!AoFfM-gWzz5pgUnkdTA-JTsi15F8

Comment: How can I refresh data, When tabbed changed in TabbedPage?