# Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException ViewModel has not been registered Autofac Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, autofac, xamarin-studio

Hey everyone I am using Autofac as my DI codebase Im following this solution [Using Navigation in MasterDetailPage with Autofac and Xamarin.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33164175/using-navigation-in-masterdetailpage-with-autofac-and-xamarin-forms) since my Press button in tabbedPage cannot navigate to next page or link page. using Button={Binding MyNextPage} in xaml.

in that solution I am a little bit confuse about this

```
     builder.RegisterInstance<Func<Page>>(() => ((NavigationPage)Application.Current.MainPage).CurrentPage);
```

As my Module I register them individually

```
   public class ClientModule : Module
   {
    //Register Here for Singleton
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        //RegServ Service
        builder.RegisterType<PersonInfoService>().As<IPersonInfoService>().SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterType<PhoneContactService>().As<IPhoneContacts>().SingleInstance();

        //RegServ View Model 
        builder.RegisterType<PersonViewModel>();
        builder.RegisterType<PhoneContactViewModelProp>();
        builder.RegisterType<LoginViewModel>(); 


        builder.RegisterType<LoginPageViewModel>().SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterType<PersonsViewModel>().SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterType<PersonDetailViewModel>().SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterType<RegistrationViewModel>().SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterType<PhoneContactViewModel>().SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterType<MainPageViewModel>().SingleInstance();


        //RegServ Views 
        builder.RegisterType<MainPage>().SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterType<BarcodePage>().SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterType<CustomScanPageView>().SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterType<CQRCodeOptionPage>().SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterType<PersonPageView>().SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterType<PersonDetailViewPage>().SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterType<RegistrationPage>().SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterType<ClientReadQRPage>().SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterType<LoginPage>().SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterType<PhoneBookPage>().SingleInstance();

    }
}
```

AutofacBootstrapper.cs

```
  namespace FormsSample.Core
  {
  public abstract class AutofacBootstrapper
  {
    public void Run()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        ConfigureContainer(builder);

        var container = builder.Build();
        var viewFactory = container.Resolve<IViewFactory>();

        RegisterViews(viewFactory);

        ConfigureApplication(container);
    }

    protected virtual void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterModule<AutofacModule>();
    }

    protected abstract void RegisterViews(IViewFactory viewFactory);

    protected abstract void ConfigureApplication(IContainer container);
  }
}
```

AutofacModule.cs

```
 namespace FormsSample.Core
 {
 public class AutofacModule : Module
 {
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        // service registration
        builder.RegisterType<ViewFactory>()
            .As<IViewFactory>()
            .SingleInstance();

        builder.RegisterType<Navigator>()
            .As<INavigator>()
            .SingleInstance();

        // navigation registration
        builder.Register<INavigation>(context =>
            App.Current.MainPage.Navigation
        ).SingleInstance();
    }
  }
}
```

Bootstrapper.cs

```
  namespace FormsSample.Core
  {
   public class Bootstrapper : AutofacBootstrapper
   {
    private readonly App _application;

    public Bootstrapper(App application)
    {
        _application = application;
    }

    protected override void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        base.ConfigureContainer(builder);
        builder.RegisterModule<ClientModule>();
       // builder.RegisterInstance<Func<Page>>(() => ((NavigationPage)Application.Current.MainPage).CurrentPage);
    }

    protected override void RegisterViews(IViewFactory viewFactory)
    {
        // register these with the view factory. ViewModel and View Page
        //Autofac <object class, Func<class, >
        viewFactory.Register<PersonsViewModel, PersonPageView>();
        viewFactory.Register<PersonDetailViewModel, PersonDetailViewPage>();
        viewFactory.Register<LoginPageViewModel, LoginPage>();
        viewFactory.Register<RegistrationViewModel, RegistrationPage>();
        viewFactory.Register<PhoneContactViewModel, PhoneBookPage>();
        viewFactory.Register<MainPageViewModel, MainPage>();
    }

    protected override void ConfigureApplication(IContainer container)
    {
        // set main page
        var viewFactory = container.Resolve<IViewFactory>();
        var mainPage = viewFactory.Resolve<MainPageViewModel>();

        var navigationPage = new NavigationPage(mainPage);
       _application.MainPage = navigationPage;
    }


   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saying

> When I replace my entire module using ...

When you actually replace your whole module with the single registration the exception explains itself. Autofac can't resolve the `MainPageViewModel` since it has not been registered.

You have to register your module and the function that resolves the current page:

```
builder.RegisterModule<ClientModule>();
builder.RegisterInstance<Func<Page>>(() => ((NavigationPage)Application.Current.MainPage).CurrentPage);
```

### Update 1

Following your last comment, I would expect the `Bootstrapper` to look like this:

```
public class Bootstrapper
{
    public static void Run()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterModule<ClientModule>();
        builder.RegisterInstance<Func<Page>>(() => ((NavigationPage)Application.Current.MainPage).CurrentPage);
        var container = builder.Build();

        var page = container.Resolve<MainPage>();
        YourApp.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(page);
    }
}
```

### Update 2

Given your example I think it should work if you do not comment out the third line in your `ConfigureContainer` method:

```
protected override void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    base.ConfigureContainer(builder);
    builder.RegisterModule<ClientModule>();
    builder.RegisterInstance<Func<Page>>(() => ((NavigationPage)Application.Current.MainPage).CurrentPage);
}
```

Comment: thats is in bootstrapper right? this one  
            base.ConfigureContainer(builder);
            builder.RegisterModule<ClientModule>();

Comment: I don't know the architecture of your application, but it looks as if that could be the correct place.

Comment: opps Im sorry im using Johnathan Yates as my model https://adventuresinxamarinforms.com/2014/11/21/creating-a-xamarin-forms-app-part-6-view-model-first-navigation/

Comment: I have updated above can you pls take a look thanks.

Comment: unfortunately it does not, i just abandon it :(